# Node teasers in node object filled with full node body if teaser is not defined

Tags: nodes

When Editor saves the Node, If teaser field is filled, normally teaser node object is filled with that content.
But if Teaser field is not filled, System is populating teaser of node object with body of the Node.

That is kind of weird because i need to detect if node has teaser or not, programatically.

Is there a workaround how i could detect programatically that Node was saved without teaser has been touched ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check summary text in node obj.

```
if (empty($node->body['und'][0]['summary'])) {
//do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i need, how i missed to see myself ? ;)